# Convert this Java regex to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I have this regex in a java file that needs to be implemented in a JS file.

`^[\p{Print}\n\r\\xa1-\xff]*$`

I am having trouble getting it to work the same way.

If there is a tool somewhere for this, please share it here.  Thanks!

Comment: Does that regex not work in JS? There's no actual Java code here

Comment: Also, note that if you want to match any non-control chars with `\p{Print}`, you may use `/^[\P{C}\n\r\xa1-\xff]*$/u` in JS.

Comment: @evolutionxbox regex in Java is a little bit different.  One difference is using two backslashes instead of one in some areas.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the tip.  Unfortunately, that regex does not work exactly the same as the one I provided.  `Ž` is not supposed to pass, but it does with what you provided.

Comment: Did you check the duplicate thread? ``/^[a-z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@\[\] ^_`{|}~-]*$/i`` cannot match `Ż` nor `Ź`, etc. Add your `\n\r\xa1-\xff` if necessary.